How to give permissions to resolve invalid image when uploading?
On my Symfony project, I've add an image field to my form following the docs. But I've an error which occurs when I submit the form after filling fields including the image. Error is the mimeTypesMessage defined in my form class :
->add('picture', FileType::class, [
  'label' => 'Illustration (jpg, png or jpeg file)',
  'mapped'=> false,
  'required' => false,
  'constraints' => [
    new File([
      'mimeTypes' => ['images/*'],
      'mimeTypesMessage' => "file : {{ file }} is not a valid image. ({{ name }}, {{ type }}, {{ types }})"
    ])
  ]
])

So the output is :
file : "C:\xampp\tmp\php714A.tmp" is not a valid image. ("matthew-hIgWo0wtx74-unsplash.jpg", "image/jpeg", "images/*")
After research, I found this post which can, I suppose, resolved my problem but I didn't understand how to give the folder all permissions, as said @krachleur, on Windows.
I've also found this Medium post but the commands is for Linux.
Same difficulty with this article of Symfony documentation and the umask() function changes nothing.
Here my code :
services.yaml
parameters:
    pictures_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/pictures'
    targetDirectory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/'
services:
    App\Service\FileUploader:
        arguments:
            $targetDirectory: '%pictures_directory%'

FileUploader :
class FileUploader {

    public function __construct(
        private string $targetDirectory,
        private SluggerInterface $slugger
    ) {
        // ...
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file): string {

        // $originalFilename = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // safe inclusion of the file name in the URL
        // $safeFilename = $this->slugger->slug($originalFilename);
        // generate a unique name and let symfony guess the right extension for don't trust the input provided by user
        $file->getError();
        $newFilename = md5(uniqid().'.'.$file->guessExtension());

        try {
            // moving file chere pictures are stored
            $file->move($this->getTargetDirectory(), $newFilename);
        } catch (FileException $fileError) {
            echo 'Erreur lors du téléchargement du fichier';
            throw $fileError;
        }

        return $newFilename;
    }

    public function getTargetDirectory(): string {

        return $this->targetDirectory;
    }
}

My controller :
#[Route('/new-ad', name: 'app_new_ad')]
    public function handleBoatAdForm(
        Request $request,
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        FileUploader $fileUploader,
        ): Response {

        $boatAd = new Boat();
        $form = $this->createForm(BoatAdType::class, $boatAd);
        Clock::set(new MockClock());
        $clock = Clock::get();
        $user = $this->getUser();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            
            $pictureFile = $form->get('picture')->getData();

            if ($pictureFile) { // check if a file is upload and processed it only in this case
                $pictureFilename = $fileUploader->upload($pictureFile);
                // updates the pictureFilename property to store the Image file instead of its contents
                $boatAd->setPictureFilename($pictureFilename);
            }
            
            $boatAd = $form->getData();
            $boatAd->setDateCreation($clock->now());
            $boatAd->setFKBoatUser($user);

            $entityManager->persist($boatAd);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_index');
        }

        return $this->render('pages/boat_ad_form/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }


You have a spelling error in your mimeTypes that is probably causing the error, it should be 'image/*' (without the extra s). Alternatively, you can use the Image constraint instead of the File one, this already sets the 'image/*' mimeType for you so you don't have to set it manually: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Image.html

I confirm that the error comes from 'images/*'. It works now (I also tried well by corrected image and by use Image constraint). Thanks !
